# Django-Amazon Elastic Bean Server, with S3 Server for Static Files gives ERROR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-admin

Using Django -

Currently, I have the following setup: I have an instance of my website running on Amazon web services Elastic Bean Instance. I have another S3 bucket purely used to serve static files only.

However, the problem I am getting is when I load the admin page for my website "mydomain.com/admin" gives me access to the link, but I noticed that the styles are not present. I did a check with the console on chrome and I saw that I was getting the following for ALL OF MY resource files:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE    
https://www.mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/jquery/ui/css/custom-them… 
2g7HF81wsUgDVNeJGTaeIUoFpgOBCqxnGz4y7Nz8uY9juJllNeWHj37%2BriCVsbefBQ%3D%3D
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE  
https://www.mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/stylesheets/screen.css?Si… 
2g7HF81wsUgDVNeJGTaeIUoFpgOBCqxnGz4y7Nz8uY9juJllNeWHj37%2BriCVsbefBQ%3D%3D
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE 
https://www.mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/stylesheets/mueller/grid/…
2g7HF81wsUgDVNeJGTaeIUoFpgOBCqxnGz4y7Nz8uY9juJllNeWHj37%2BriCVsbefBQ%3D%3D
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

If I actually click on those links and then go to it, it leads me to an insecure page and then I click to open it and then reload my page on mysite.com/admin, it works just fine and all the resources load, but if I go on a cleared browser instance, the samething would happen. Also, it shouldn't be doing this. Do I need to allow amazon s3 policies or some type of CORS configuration? I have done the following CORS configurations:

THIS IS FOR THE BUCKET WHICH IS CURRENTLY HOSTING MY WEBSITE. THIS IS NOT THE BUCKET THAT SERVES THE STATIC FILES.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 9):

If your bucket name actually has a dot in it, you can't mix the virtual-style URLs and https.

```
https://bucket.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/foo # insecure
https://s3.amazonaws.con/bucket.example.com/foo # secure
```

This is because a wildcard SSL cert, like S3 provides, is only good for one additional "dot level" in the hostname, which is the dot right before "s3.amazonaws.com" ... more than one dot to the left of the "s3.amazonaws.com" amd the browser will detect a mismatch between the cert and the site names... importantly, too, you must replace "s3" with an appropriate regional endpoint for your bucket, if using the 2nd form of URL, above, any time the bucket isn't in the US Standard region, e.g. for a bucket "bucket.example.com" in the us-west-2 region and a file called "foo"...

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.example.com/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example of 'Michael - sqlbot'.

> https://bucket.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/foo # = ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>   https://s3.amazonaws.con/bucket.example.com/foo # = OK

The domain solution before 's3.amazonaws.com'

If you replace (.) by (-) works.

> https://bucket-example-com.s3.amazonaws.com/foo # = OK

Comment: This requires changing the bucket's name to not use dots... you can't simply refer to "this.bucket.s3..." as "this-bucket.s3..." since those are two different buckets.